# failing to load ROracle: unable to load shared object ROracle.so: libclntsh.so.11.1 No such file or directory

Tags: oracle, r, rstudio

So I can't load ROracle. I am indeed very new to this so any information is appreciated and any info regarding what further information to give would be helpful as well.

```
> library(ROracle)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so':
  libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘ROracle’
```

ROracle.so is exactly where it says it is. libclntsh.so.11.1 can be found at `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1`. This is the result of `.libPaths`:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/nguiller/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                     "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                          
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"                                "/usr/lib/rstudio/R/library"
```

My .Renviron file

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:/home/nguiller/Downloads/instantclient_11_2"
ORACLE_HOME="/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/:/home/nguiller/Downloads/instantclient_11_2"
OCI_LIB="/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib"
```

I had a lot of trouble installing ROracle to begin with due to OCI libraries but it eventually worked with `R CMD INSTALL --configure-ags='--with-oci-lib=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib --with-oci-inc=/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64' ROracle_1.1-8.tar.gz`

Let me know how I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORACLE_HOME should point to just one location. Shouldn't you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64 variable?

Comment: This worked after I exported the env variables (.Renviron doesn't seem to work). Thank you so much!



`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:/home/nguiller/Downloads/instantclient_11_2" && export ORACLE_HOME="/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/" && export OCI_LIB="/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib" && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64="/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:/home/nguiller/Downloads/instantclient_11_2"`

Comment: I have the exact same problem
<br/><br/>
<div style="dIsplay: inline-block;">
    library(ORE)
    Loading required package: OREdm
    Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
      unable to load shared object '/home/usernamehere/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-    gnu-library/3.2/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so':
  libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package ‘OREdm’ could not be loaded
</div>
<br/><br/>
you make reference to instantclient_11_2 in the user dir . how did you get that there ... unsipped files ?

Comment: @Madmartigan Check your installation (file is there...) and environment variables (library path(s) for your platform)

Comment: cheers , I had a bloody typo..which I looked at so many times... your correct the LD_LIBRARY_PATH was the one that needed the instantclient_11_2 location... all good now ... happy days :)

Comment: Heads up - on some linux distros you have to modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf` per [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025911/roracle-not-working-in-r-studio/36822521#36822521) post on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you really really really want to do this within the R environment, you can load the specific library as follows:

```
dyn.load("/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1")
library(ROracle)
```

References:

[Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH from inside R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494585/setting-ld-library-path-from-inside-r)

Answer (score -1):

I got same error while loading "library(ORE)"

```
  Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
      unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so':
      libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Error: package 'OREdm' could not be loaded
```

Looks like the shared object ROracle.so is referring to libclntsh.so.11.1 instead of libclntsh.so.12.1

```
bash-4.1$ pwd
/usr/lib64/R/library
bash-4.1$ grep -irsh "libclntsh.so.11.1" *
Binary file ROracle/libs/ROracle.so matches
```

As a work around, I have created a symlink, so that libclntsh.so.12.1 can be referred as libclntsh.so.11.1.

```
$ cd /scratch/softwares/R/db_instant_client/instantclient_12_1

 ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so.11.1
```

After this step, I am able to load  library(ORE) successfully.

Please see [my website](http://rajiv-kuriakose.blogspot.in/2016/03/how-to-install-oracle-r-enterprise-on.html) for more details.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please be careful when including links to your own sites or blogs -- you should always disclose your affiliation.  See [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for detailed guidance.

Answer (score -1):

set $LD_LIBARARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib

Answer (score -1):

Set this in `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf`

```
rsession-ld-library-
path=/usr/lib64/R/lib:/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1/lib
```

Then restart Rserver

```
sudo rstudio-server stop
sudo rstudio-server start
```

This helped me.

Comment: The /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf is readonly.