# ROracle not working in R studio

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server, roracle

I'm trying to install ROracle package on a unix box.
The package gets installed properly. But library(ROracle) does not work fine with the error

```
library(ROracle)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/u01/group1/home/oracle/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so':
libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ROracle’
```

The package installs fine from the command line , but just does not work in R studio. I went through lot of threads in forum and lot of them suggested to export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and reset it.infact i went ahead and copied all the R system variables from command line into R Studio.
But it still does not work out fine.

One thing i have also noticed is that the R system variables change every time i restart R studio. Can it be the problem that R studio is not taking path values correctly.

Comment: It doesn't work in RStudio, but it works in vanilla R from the console?

Comment: Yes Roman. U are right

Comment: I had another thought. Why is this tagged rstudio-server? Are you accessing R through the server or directly?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Were you able to make it work on the Rstudio?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue in CentOS - and all "usual supects" env variables look correct from within RStudio (LD_LIBRARY_PATH, ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882033/failing-to-load-roracle-unable-to-load-shared-object-roracle-so-libclntsh-so-1 `dyn.load("/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1"); library(ROracle)`

Answer (score 13):

Seems that the problem is caused by the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable not being set in a way that is system-wide.  Unlike other environment variables, **$LD_LIBRARY_PATH needs special treatment** (see the [Ubuntu Help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) and search for **ld.so.conf.d**)

I was able to solve this by setting the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH as per [comment 15](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/366728):

`echo "/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib" | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf`

Change the echo statement to where your Oracle Instant Client libraries are stored.  (Mine could be found by running `echo $OCI_LIB`.

Then update the cache:

`sudo ldconfig -v`

Then open RStudio, execute `library("ROracle")` and it should work.

Comment: [Josh Gilfilla](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3827849/josh-gilfillan)n, I found your answer very helpful. To people administering Debian based systems that interface with Oracle, I would highly recommend reading the following documentation regarding [shared libraries](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

Comment: @Zerodf, glad it was helpful.  Any chance of an up-vote? :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem, and I have just resolved it thanks to a conference with some very kind and helpful Oracle personnel.

We need to include the following line in `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf` file (which [by default is empty](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552316-Configuring-the-Server)):

```
rsession-ld-library-path=/usr/lib64/R/lib:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/lib
```

i.e. the R & Oracle home directories:

```
$ echo $R_HOME
/usr/lib64/R
$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1
```

You have to restart the RStudio server after modifying the configuration file.

I have checked this only with RStudio server, so not sure if it is necessary for RStudio Desktop, too...

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57012_01/doc.141/e57007/apx_rstudio.htm#BABIEAIE) for more details (although it refers to Oracle R Enterprize, it is also applicable to vanilla R).