# Unable to load package ROracle in R

Tags: r, roracle

So, I can't load `ROracle`.

I am indeed very new to this so any information is appreciated and any info regarding what further information to give would be helpful as well.

> Warning: Error in : package or namespace load failed for ‘ROracle’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so':
>   libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

And for my Environmental variables I get

`Sys.getenv("ORACLE_HOME")
[1] "/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib"`

So I see I have version 12.1 but `ROracle` is looking for 11.1, what can I do?

Comment: Did you check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025911/roracle-not-working-in-r-studio/36822521#36822521)

Comment: Okay, I tried. Doesn't work. I've restarted the shiny server but it doesn't help. Do I have to restart R server to? How do i do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay I had several .libPaths() and I had to install the package in every single Path. This has solved the problem.

Comment: But how you got that?