# Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH from inside R

Tags: r, unix, linker-flags

I have installed an R package but, in order to load it via `library`, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH needs to be set to the path where one of the libraries, called `libhts.so.2` is located. The loading only works when editing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH before going into R, **not after**.

I have tried several different methods in solving this:

1. exporting a modified LD_LIBRARY_PATH from the `configure` script located in the R package.
2. Creating a soft link to the shared library within the same `configure` script.

Both have **not** worked and it seems to me that there is a variable that stores the results of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH once R is started. Maybe the solution is editing that variable.

Comment: Calling `Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/blah")` from within `R` will change the environment of any future subprocess, but not that of `R` itself (which can be seen with `ps e`). Still, [this post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-seems-to-mangle-LD-LIBRARY-PATH-td4686672.html) seems to indicate that it makes a difference, so you could give it a try.

Comment: .. or rather `Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH=paste("/path/to/blah", Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"),sep=":")) ` in order not to clobber the existing path

Comment: Setting the environment variables works! However, the loading of the library doesn't work...

Comment: The [guide](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_94.html) to writing R extensions says: _On Unix-alikes the paths used to resolve dynamically linked dependent libraries are fixed (for security reasons) when the process is launched (...)_. I'm afraid that means that your problem is not solvable: any solution would be considered a security risk....

Comment: I'll definitely read that but, I tried dyn.load(path_to_library) and it worked! In your opinion, what do you think about that? Would it be a security risk?

Comment: I suppose that when changing a search path you may shoot yourself in the foot (like with the classic `PATH=.:$PATH`). With `dyn.load` you give an _absolute_ pathname, so you (presumably) know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Btw, I think you should give your solution - using `dyn.load()` - as an answer, if it really did solve your problem. It would help other people, and I would certainly vote it up.

Comment: @HansLub Thanks! I submitted an answer.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this is the case.  The installer usually tests for loading and should have caught this during installation.  Did you copy the **.so** object from someone else's R library path?  I would think the proper solution here is to reinstall the package, with the correct LD_LIBRARY_PATH set during installation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With help from **Hans Lub**, the way to solve the problem is by using the `dyn.load()` function and supplying the full path to the library:

```
dyn.load('path_to_library')
```

and then, loading via `library` should work.

Comment: Yes, this works BUT if you want to install a new package the installation happens in a fresh environment and there is no opportunity to use dyn.load() prior to the installation attempting to load the DLL.

Comment: For example: if I install rJava referring to libjvm.so somewhere under $HOME (because I don't have root privileges) then I have to use dyn.load("/home/...../libjvm.so") prior to loading rJava. No problem. But when I try to install RJDBC the installation script attempts to load rJava and falls in a heap.

Comment: @MichaelHenry You can use `withr::with_makevars` for that case, where you add an `-L/path/to/library` to the `PKG_LIBS` variable.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45178482/570918

Comment: In case you can edit `$prefix/lib/R/etc/ldpaths` - e.g. when having built R from source with a user space compiler you are all set. I think the install process (of `R`) built from source is kind of broken as it does not update the load path bootstrap from the build environment. But, fortunately post editing the `etc/ldpaths` content to inject the path works for me. Is there maybe a more elegant way?